# Limit textarea characters by ID jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, limit, each

**The goal:** I'm trying to limit all my text boxes in all DIV ID named #boom1.

**The problem:** Can't get them all (a problem with the loop method in my opinion)

$(function () {

```
var maxL = 300;

$('#boom1').each(function (i, div) { //I got lost with syntax over here

    var text = $('#boom1').text();
    if(text.length > maxL) {

        var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
            end = text.substr(maxL);

        $('#boom1').html(begin)
            .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').attr('href', '#').html('read more...'))
            .append($('<div class="hidden" />').html(end));
    }

});

$(document).on('click', '.readmore', function () {
    $(this).next('.hidden').slideDown(750);
})
```

})

I'll be glad to get some help, with syntax if possible..

Thanks.

Attaching a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s4ty/dyajA/2/#&togetherjs=VARdCiqUmn)

Comment: why would you have multiple div's with the same id? that's not really correct. and it might be the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using following code, working fine

```
$(function () {

    var maxL = 300;


    $('.wp-caption-text').each(function (i, div) {
        //alert("dfs");
        var text = $(this).text();
        if(text.length > maxL) {

            var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                end = text.substr(maxL);

            $(this).html(begin)
                .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').attr('href', '#').html('read more...'))
                .append($('<div class="hidden" />').html(end));

        }

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function () {
        $(this).next('.hidden').slideDown(750);
    })        


})
```

Comment: Thanks man! An excellent solution. It was smart and quick!
Perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

    var maxL = 300;

    $('#boom1').each(function () { // If you don't use them you won't need them here

        var text = $('#boom1').text();
        if(text.length > maxL) {

            var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                end = text.substr(maxL);

            $('#boom1').html(begin)
                .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').attr('href', '#').html('read more...'))
                .append($('<div class="hidden" />').html(end));
        }

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function () {
        $(this).next('.hidden').slideDown(750);
    });  



});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3AeS/)

id must be unique.

Use  classes for multiple usage .

added class `boom` to each div.

added `read less...` and `read more...` toggling feature too.

`$(this)` refers to the current element in the loop.

```
$(function () {
    var maxL = 300;
    $('.boom').each(function (i, div) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length > maxL) {

            var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                end = text.substr(maxL);

            $(this).html(begin)
                .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').attr('href', '#').html('read more...'))
                .append($('<div class="hidden" />').html(end));
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.readmore', function () {
        $(this).html(function(_,ctr){
            return (ctr == 'read more...') ? 'read less...':'read more...'
        });
        $(this).next('.hidden').slideToggle(750);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` makes you loop through all instances of an element, so you shouldn't use an ID. The following would iterate on every "some-class" element.

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
<div class="some-class"></div>    


$('.some-class').each(function (i, div) {/* code*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use each on an id - it will only get you the first one. Identifiers should be unique and only appear once per page. So only the first one will be used.

Try adding a class to each '#boom1'.. for example '.boom-class' and then doing jQuery each on it.